# Is this intended (* in chats)

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, chat, markdown

It is stated in the stackoverflow FAQ: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting

```
*italic* or _italic_
**bold** or __bold__
```

so when I type three * followed by a word followed by another three * I expect to see the word to appear to be both italic and bold. Now this is work correctly.

Today I was formatting some message in a chat, I accidentally typed in this:

```
*this = ***that***
```

It appeared to read "this = ****that***" (with 'that' appeared to be bold & italic).

Is this not a bug?

Answer (score 13):

No, that is not a bug.

It is interpreted as such:

```
*                *
 this = *
         **that**
```

so the outer stars surround `this = ***that**` making the whole text italic, bolding `that`, leaving the one extra asterisk hanging. The text is ambiguous at best; other markdown interpreters may leave the *first* asterisk hanging instead, like the parser used for posting questions and answers:

*this = ***that***

clearly interpreted as

```
*this =           
       *        *
        **that**
```

The Markdown standard doesn't specify how such ambiguous mixing should be handled, both interpretations are equally valid.

If you expected a specific interpretation, use `\*` to remove a given asterisk from consideration and use HTML tags (`<em>` for italics, `<strong>` for bolding) for the emphasis as needed:

```
*this = \*<strong>that</strong>*
```

renders as

*this = ***that***

Comment: you mean, HTML <em>in comments</em>? \\* renders as \*, though, so *\*escape\**

Comment: @JanDvorak: Comments are a different parser *again*.

Comment: Then there's the multi-line chat parser... :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: The multi-line parser assumes *no* formatting, unless you indent 4 spaces, at which point it always formats with `<pre>`.